# Is there any way to specify keyboard type?

Tags: android, keyboard

I can find which keypad is used by the function:

```
    Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                              Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD)
```

But what I want to know is which keypad mode is used.
For example, querty, 3*4 or Handwriting recognition from GalaxyS' default keypad.
Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

This is specific to keyboard and I think is not implemented in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The `imeOptions` property on objects that have it (e.g., any subclass of TextView`) can be set or read to determine what will be given to the IME as a hint for what keyboard configuration will be used.

Don't assume too much based on what you get out of it, because the property is advisory and IMEs aren't required to honor it.